# split a string by anything that is not a word or number

Tags: python, regex, split

All

I have numpy.ndarray thats contains strings in each row, whose dimensions are (600, ).

I have written code that, I assume, finds everything that is not a word or number.

What I want to do is split the string, that only contains words or numbers.
All the strings are different and may have certain characters that others dont.

For example:
"[Name] Jayganesh [laSt] Kalla [age] 24 , this is so cool!!!"

It shoudl return:
['Name', 'Jayganesh', 'laSt', 'age', '24', 'this', 'is', 'so', cool']
Input:

```
 re.findall(r'\W', summary_data[23,])
```

Output:

```
['[',
 ']',
 ' ',
 '[',
 ']',
 ' ',
 ' ',
 ' ',
 ' ',
 ' ',
 "'",
 ' ',
 ' ',
 ' ',
 ' ',
 ' ',
 ' ',
 ' ']
```

I think I am on the right track and have tried using the split function, but it did not work.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I can assure you the `split` function works. On your shown attempt: why not search for **word** characters if **non-word** characters give you an exact list of things you don't want?

Comment: How about `map(lambda x: x.strip("[]!"), s.split())`?

Comment: Try `re.split(r'[\W_]+', data)`. If it is Python 2.x, use `re.split(r'[\W_]+', data, re.U)`

Comment: @usr2564301 I know `split` function works, but when i use it, i get this error `'list' object has no attribute 'split'
`

Comment: Great, it means you do not supply a string as the input argument. Please provide exact data to test against.